# Many ways of comparing two strings in pascal doesn't work for me

Tags: string, pascal

I was doing an assignment on `Pascal`. I almost get everything done except try to compare two strings to check if the game is done. But when I compare them inside the `guess` procedure, it always stands false even if the `encryption` string already is the same as `theWord` string. I do not quite understand how Pascal deals with string. Then, I try to compare them in `main`, which output `true`. I am really confused. I tried `SameStr`, `CompareText`, `=`, all of them turn out to be the same result.

Code:

```
program hangman;
Uses sysutils;

const 
    times = 6;

var
    theWordSize,i : integer;
    theWord,encryption : string;

function encrypt (): string;
var
    list : string;
begin
    for i := 1 to theWordSize do
        list[i] := '*';
    encrypt := list;
end;

procedure reveal(letter: char);
begin
    for i := 1 to theWordSize do
        if (theWord[i] = letter) then
            encryption[i] := theWord[i];
end;

procedure guess();
var
    letter : char;
    j : integer;
begin
    writeln('hello');
    j := times;
    while (j > 0) do
        begin
            writeln('Guess a letter( ':16, j:1, ' times left ): ':15);
            readln(letter);
            if pos(letter,theWord)<>0 then    // guess correctly
                begin
                    reveal(letter);
                    writeln('Correct! Word: ':15, encryption:7);
                    writeln(SameText(theWord,encryption));
                    if SameText(theWord,encryption) then
                    begin
                        writeln('You win!   The correct word: ':28, theWord:7);
                        exit
                    end;
                    inc(j)
                end
            else if (j > 1) then                // guess wrong
                writeln('Wrong!   Word: ':15, encryption:7)
            else
                writeln('You lose! The man is dead.   Correct Word: ':43, theWord:7);
            dec(j)
        end
end;

{* Main program: *}
begin
    theWord := 'mystery';
    theWordSize := byte(theWord[0]);
    //writeln(theWord[i]=='m');
    writeln('Weclome to Hangman game:');
    encryption := encrypt();
    writeln('Mystery Word: ':14, encryption:theWordSize);
    guess();
    for i := 0 to theWordSize do
        encryption[i] := theWord[i];
    writeln(SameText(theWord,encryption));
end.
```

Part of the running results:

```
Guess a letter( 6 times left ): 
e
Correct! Word: m*ste**
FALSE
Guess a letter( 6 times left ): 
r
Correct! Word: m*ster*
FALSE
Guess a letter( 6 times left ): 
y
Correct! Word: mystery
FALSE
Guess a letter( 6 times left ): 
a
Wrong!   Word: mystery
Guess a letter( 5 times left ): 
a
Wrong!   Word: mystery
Guess a letter( 4 times left ): 
a
Wrong!   Word: mystery
Guess a letter( 3 times left ): 
a
Wrong!   Word: mystery
Guess a letter( 2 times left ): 
a
Wrong!   Word: mystery
Guess a letter( 1 times left ): 
a
You lose! The man is dead.   Correct Word: mystery
TRUE
```

Comment: One of the purposes of programming assignments is to develop your own debugging skills, but different Pascal implementations vary in the quality of their debugging facilities.  Are you doing this using FreePascal + its IDE, Lazarus, or if not, what?

Comment: Yup, I am using FreePascal. My assignment is doing this in a set of languages. I already implemented this algorithm in different languages but only stuck here in Pascal. And I really cannot figure out what's wrong here. Maybe your help will be a big difference. Thanks.

Comment: Well, if you are using FPC with Lazarus (which is free and easy to install if you don't have it already), put a debugger breakpoint on the line `   while (j > 0) do` and run the program under the debugger until the breakpoint trips.  Then single step the code (using F8) and use F7 to evaluate the value of variables, observe what happens and figure out why it behaves as it does.  Fwiw, it's higly unlikely (read, impossible) that the program will fail because it's not finding that two identical strings are equal.  So you have a mistake somewhere ...

Comment: You are relying on an implementation detail when you refer to the 0 index of short strings. In general I consider this a no-no to do. It is always safer to use library methods when such are available, like `SetLength()` to set the length and `Length()` to get the length of strings et al. These functions work correctly for all kind of strings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a sort of code of honour at SO that where homework is involved, we don't
just tell you the answer.  So instead, I'm going to show you the way to use Lazarus'
debugger to identify the cause of your problem yourself.  The thing is, a compiler like fpc wouldn't survive very long if it couldn't make string comparisons correctly, so the reason functions like SameText are failing must be because the strings you are comparing are not, in fact, equal.  The question is "why not?" and finding out is what debugging is all about.

If you haven't installed Lazarus yet, do so now and open your project in it.  If,
the first time you compile your Hangman in it you get the error

> Hangman.lpr(64,56) Error: Element zero of an ansi/wide- or longstring cannot be accessed, use (set)length instead

that's because Lazarus is assuming you are using so-called "Huge strings", which
can be up to 2Gb in size, whereas you are obviously intending to use traditional
Pascal "ShortStrings" which are arrays of up to 255 characters preceded by a length byte.

To force Lazarus to use ShortStrings, add

```
$mode objfpc}{$H-}
```

just below `program Hangman.  Also while you are at it, change

```
theWordSize := byte(theWord[0]);
```

to

```
theWordSize := Length(theWord);
```

because that will work regardless of HugeStrings versus ShortStrings and makes
no assumptions as to the internal structure of a string.

The next step I'd take is to alter the line which sets `theWord` to

```
theWord := 'm'; //'mystery';
```

so as to minimize the amount of typing during debugging.  Then, put a debugger
breakpoint on the line

```
    if SameText(theWord,encryption) then
```

by clicking near the LH edge of the gutter (the area that has the source line numbers
in it).

Compile and run the program, and once the console window appears, type

> m<kbd>Return</kbd>

Once you've done that, the debugger stops at the breakpoint.  Press <kbd>F8</kbd>
to single-step the debugger, and you'll find that it goes to the

```
inc(J);
```

so obviously `SameText` failed, which is where you came in with your q.  There's no point
in carrying on with the current run of the app beyond that, so press <kbd>Ctrl-F7</kbd> to terminate it and reset the debugger.

Run the app again and look carefully at the result of executing the line

```
writeln('Mystery Word: ':14, encryption:theWordSize);
```

and you'll notice that it doesn't display anything for the value of
`encryption`.  This is a BIG clue to what's going wrong.  The 'm' you
typed wasn't wrong, so `encryption` CANNOT have the same value.  The only
thing left to do is to find out what value it actually has.  Notice that
if you try to evaluate `encryption` using <kbd>F7</kbd>, it shows a blank,
not the asterisk you would expect.

For the next bit, put a breakpoint on the line

```
for i := 1 to theWordSize do
```

in the `encrypt` function and drag the code window to the right on the screen. Then, press 
to open the `Watches` window, if necessary drang it into the space freed by moving the code window and enter the following expressions into it

```
list[0]
```

and

```
list[1]
```

This is to enable you to observe the values in the length byte and first character of list.
Run the app until the `encrypte` breakpoint and then single-step around the
`for` loop. You will find that the value of

```
list[0]
```

doesn't change, even after the value of `list[1]` has been set to 'm'.

So, what's returned by `encrypt` is an empty string, QED, and I'm sure you will realise
how to fix it. Sorry if this has been rather gruelling but at least it should
give you an idea how to systematically debug the next problem you run into.

Comment: Has this solved your problem or do you need more help?

Comment: Yes!! Thanks a lot sir!

Comment: Then it would be great if you would accept the answer by clicking the "tick" icon on its left.

Comment: Sorry, I am new here.